# How to specify a time zone in UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, datepicker

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed {
NSDate *selected = [datePicker date];
NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"The date and time you selected is: %@", selected];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"Date and Time Selected" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes, I did!" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
[message release];
```

So my question is next... How can I specify a time zone using a Datepicker in Objective C?
now if I choose some values from DatePicker and press the button which displays an alert - the time is wrong. It's probably because of incorrect time zone but I'm not sure. Well any ideas would be great. On the picture below you can see that I chose 2:14 PM (14:14) but an alter says that it is 11:14 and the time zone is +000

**UPDATE 1**
I have added a few changes to my code but still nothing...

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed {
NSDate *selected = [datePicker date];       
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];    
NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:tz];
NSString *formattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:selected];
NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"The date and time you selected is: %@", formattedDate];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"Date and Time Selected" 
                      message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes, I did!" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
[message release];
[dateFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 17):

Use this at the point where use defined your datepicker

**datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];**

Answer (score 6):

You can set the date with timezone

**Objective C**

```
datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:10*60*60]; // Like GMT+10
```

**in Swift 3:**

```
datePicker.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 5*60*60)  // Like GMT+5
```

Answer (score 5):

in Swift 3:

```
datePicker.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the date with timezone strings like `Australia/West (+08:00) , WST, Asia/Kolkata (+05:30)` , IST

```
datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"timezone string goes here"] ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because of the date format being picked, use an NSDateFormatter to specify the appropriate date format and use it in your string, here is a link [Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss"] - is what I am need! Thank you very much Daniel